# Conditionally apply optionality to an object key

Tags: typescript

I have a util type to make mutually exclusive unions from a type:

```
type MutuallyExclusive<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    [K2 in keyof T]: K2 extends K ? T[K2] : never;
  };
}[keyof T];
```

And from this:

```
interface Attributes {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  username: string;
}

type ExclusiveAttributesResult = MutuallyExclusive<Attributes>;
```

I get this:

```
type ExclusiveAttributesResult = {
    id: string;
    email: never;
    username: never;
} | {
    id: never;
    email: string;
    username: never;
} | {
    id: never;
    email: never;
    username: string;
}
```

Can the above be modified to apply optionality to the key when `K2 extends K`? I'd like to end up with:

```
type ExclusiveAttributesResult = {
    id: string;
    email?: never;
    username?: never;
} | {
    id?: never;
    email: string;
    username?: never;
} | {
    id?: never;
    email?: never;
    username: string;
}
```

Comment: You're going to need an intersection in there somewhere; TS doesn't allow you to conditionally make a key optional directly.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WY2B3w) for an example.

Comment: The question got closed, but I think I got what you were looking for: https://tsplay.dev/Nn5Xew with a slightly different typing (no never values)